# Help needed for lyrics. Artist: SLDGHMR Track: Deviate

Tags: lyrics, electronic-music

I'm unable to understand the lyrics when listening to:
https://soundcloud.com/sldghmr/deviate-ft-la-felix
No matter how hard I try, its only gibberish to me.

There are no resources on the web with lyrics for that track. I searched really exhaustively.

Does someone know a resource or does someone understand the lyrics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**V1:** I want to feel like I used to feel before
Some soul groove to inspire me some more.

**Bridge:** When I don't know where to turn, I turn to you
But you just don't do the things that you used to do

**Chorus:** So give me more spine for my back beats
And drop that bass note to (eh) fly beats
My shoes sparkling and fancy
Let's deviate, let's deviate

**V2:** Oh you've changed, oh you've changed
I don't know what to do
Oh, I've made all I've made
But I go nuts again.

**Bridge/Chorus**

Let's deviate

**V3:** This club shivering
At the core

Let's deviate (x9)

Comment: Cool thank you. I hope someone can fill in the last gaps. So far the content of this tune is nonsense. I was expecting this, but better nonsense than gibberish.

Comment: Well, not more nonsensical than most song lyrics.  The verse section is addressed to his lover, the chorus is about dancing to the music.